# ansible Syntax error counting hosts in inventory groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

I am unable to get around this syntax problem even after searching online. any hint?

my need is to count the number of hosts in all groups for now two in the inventory file.

task

```
#Validate cluster nodes to inventory specification
      - assert:
          that:
            - "groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length >= 1"
            - "groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length >= 1"
          msg: "Assure k8s_nodes are not empty"

#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - name: Inventory validation
        hosts: localhost
        gather_facts: false
        vars:
          GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
          CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
        tasks:
          - assert:
              that:
                - "GPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
                - "CPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
```

OR

```
      - name: Inventory validation
        vars:
          GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
          CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
```

output same for any option tried above.

```
#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - name: Inventory validation
        ^ here
```

TASK with no name:

```
#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - hosts: localhost
        gather_facts: false
        vars:
          GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
          CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
        tasks:
          - assert:
              that:
                - "GPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
                - "CPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
```

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>

The error appears to be in '/home/du/ansible/roles/3_validations_on_ssh/tasks/main.yaml': line 45, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - hosts: localhost
        ^ here
```

inventory

```
target1 ansible_host='{{ target1_hostip }}' ansible_ssh_pass='{{ target1_pass }}'
[k8s_gpu_nodes]
host1
host2
[k8s_cpu_nodes]
host3
host4
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you respect the **[YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html)**, especially in term of indentation.

For instance: `- nam`e should start at the beginning of the line, without any space in front of it.

Comment: I doubt indentation is problem coz, if i disable this task and run, rest all tasks are executed well which are in same indentation. I added another task above. please observe.

Comment: @AhmFM OK, and would that work without a name? Directly with `- host:`

Comment: Updated that option also above in question. does not help.

Comment: @AhmFM I meant, without a `-name` at all, the section would start directly with `- hosts: localhost`. What is the exact error message you have?

Comment: added that also in above question.

Answer (score 0):

i got it tested successfully in my ansible2.8 environment.. check if you have missed any indentation at host, vars, tasks, assert.. etc. pasting the one that i have tested..

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
      GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
      CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
  tasks:
     - assert:
         that:
            - "GPU_COUNT | int >= 1"
            - "CPU_COUNT | int >= 1"
         msg: "Assure k8s_nodes are not empty"
```

output:

```
TASK [assert] ***************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: GPU_COUNT | int >= 1
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assure k8s_nodes are not empty
```

output: when i change both to greater than or equal

```
TASK [assert] ******************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  msg: All assertions passed
```

Comment: Seriously, can't get it. I have ansible 2.8.5 and I get ``` - hosts: localhost ^ here``` Now, I removed all tasks and just added yours and get same error . am adding my solution now but am again stuck with variable out of scope. please observe its output.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I got rid of the syntax error was switching to below.. but I want to understand the reason here and not blindly agree. 
but even with this I have error in output that GPU_COUNT is out of scope. However, atleast i solved my original syntax concern.

```
      - debug:
        vars:
            GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
            CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
      - assert:
               that:
                  - "GPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
                  - "CPU_COUNT | int >= 1"
               msg: "Assure k8s_nodes are not empty"
```

output: how to fix below?

```
TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : assert] **********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'GPU_COUNT | int <= 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (GPU_COUNT | int <= 1): 'GPU_COUNT' is undefined"}
```